# Page-Break-Before: Right not working in Edge 84 browser

Tags: html, css, page-break

I am trying to use page-break-after: right property in my HTML. It is working fine with IE but not working in Edge 84 browser. It is not adding blank page, to make second div to be printed in right side of pane.

```html
 <html xmlns:bm="urn:xyz">
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
      html {
      height: 100%;
      }

      body {
      font-family: 'Times New Roman';
      font-size: 12pt;
      min-height: 100%;

      }

      @media screen {
      .page-footer{display:none;}
      page-break-after: right;    

      }    

      @media print {
      #pagebreak {
      page-break-after: always;

      }

       div {
      overflow:initial !important
       }
      }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="window.print()">  
        <div id="EmptyPage" >      
            <p >Should print on Page1</p>
        </div>   

        <div id="EmptyPage" style="page-break-before: right;">     
            <p>Should print on Page3</p>
        </div>   
    </body>
</html>
```